# Insert date to an empty dataframe

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I want to insert a date variable val_date into the 1st row of the data frame defined below:

```
Val_Date <- as.date("6/30/2016","mdy")
```

This the defined dataframe:

```
loan_rep_sch <- data.frame(l_time=as.integer(),l_date=as.Date(character()),age=as.integer(),year=as.integer(),l_month=as.integer(),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The code used to insert the 1st row is :

```
loan_rep_sch[1,] <- c(0,Val_Date,Age,0,0)
```

but this error message pops up:

> Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

How to do so?

Comment: Hard to pack more errors into a question preamble:The function name is `as.Date` and "mdy" is not a format string that `as.Date` will accept, and `Val_Date` will not be recognized as the same as `val_date`.

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify the correct `format` when we are using the `as.Date` from `base R`.

```
as.Date("6/30/2016", format = "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "2016-06-30"
```

However, the `mdy`is from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
mdy("6/30/2016")
#[1] "2016-06-30"
```